# Add rust to image texture

Tags: image

I am new to blender. What I am trying to do is create rust on some 3D objects.

I tried adding rust to a cylinder and it gave me some decent results, but when I used the same procedure to generate rust over an image texture it's giving strange results.

Thanks
Ankit

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

in the material you show you're using a *Bump* node, which creates these 3D bumps, but it doesn't create any color. Maybe try to mix the black/red/white *ColorRamp* with the *Image Texture* node in a *Color > MixRGB*, and try *Multiply* mode for example:

[image]